# can't change vue-form-wizard props

Tags: vue.js

Im using Laravel and VueJs to create a new app and i've installed vue-form-wizard to create a multistep form, but, i cant change the props from that form.

For example, im trying to change the button 'Next' to 'The Next Step' and it's not working so far:

Theres my component so far:

form.vue

```
<template>
  <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
    <h2 slot="title"></h2>
    <tab-content title="step1" icon="fas fa-info" >
      step 1
    </tab-content>
    <tab-content title="step2" icon="far fa-file-alt">
      step 2
    </tab-content>
    <tab-content title="step3" icon="fas fa-paint-brush">
      step 3
    </tab-content>
    <tab-content title="step4" icon="fas fa-drum-steelpan">
     step 4
    </tab-content>
  </form-wizard>
</template>
    
<script>
import { FormWizard, TabContent } from "vue-form-wizard";
import "vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css";

export default {
  props: {
   nextButtonText: {
        type: String,
        default: 'The next step'
    }
},
  methods: {
    onComplete: function () {
      alert("Yay. Done!");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

any advice on that?

Answer (score 0):

Noob alert:

Forgot to set the props on form-wizard tag. Solved like that:

```
<form-wizard
    @on-complete="onComplete"
    :title="null"
    :subtitle="null"
    nextButtonText="The Next Step"
  >
```

and done!